# update query doesnt work in laravel and showing 404 error

Tags: laravel

when i edit something and press button it jest show error 404 and my form doesnt change

```html
<form action="users/edit/{{$user->id}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
        <label for="name" class="form-label">اسم</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  name="name" value="{{$user->name}}">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="lastname" class="form-label">فامیلی:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name"  name="last_name"  value="{{$user->last_name}}">
    </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >ثبت</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

##### Update query

```php
Route::post('/users/edit/{id}', function (Request $request, $id) {
    DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->update([
            'id' => $request->id,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
        ]);

    return 'done';
```

I think I have a minor mistake, can you help?

I'm new in laravel can you help me with this

Comment: Tried `action="/users/edit/{{$user->id}}"`?

Comment: Unrelated: `for="lastname"` there is no element with that `id`

Comment: @brombeer  thanks its fixed with adding this  its so annoying=))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: why are you updating the ids?

Comment: @krisgjika i dont.  its not in my form and i just add everything to fix this error

Comment: `update(['id'=>$request->id,...` looks like you're updating the `id` though

Answer (score 1):

Using these codes is really strange. I don't know which source you used to develop your code in this way!
Code example using controller and model

in route:

```
Route::put('users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'update'])
->name('users.update');
```

in controller

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    //$request->validate([]); validate your request
    $user->update($request->all());

 
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'your message');
}
```

in view

```
<form action="{{ route('users.update', $user) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')

    your form data ...
</form>
```